# Pay for updates in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, updates

We are developing a android application, it is free, this free version install the main content of app, but we want the user pay for more content, in the following way :

```
app with main content : FREE
update with more content 1 : $2
update with more content 2 : $2
.
.
update with more content n : $2
```

Is it supported by the android market?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a third party service which may change at any time, and is best asked to the company.

Answer (score 1):

After you publish your app, there is a option to add new "in-app products". To use this, when you publish your app, you must include the "BILLING" permission.

https://market.android.com/publish

Of course you could use brute force and have a separate free "Lite" version that hyperlinks to a pay version of your app.

Comment: So, you mean that the only way to collect pays for updates is with my own implementation of a site where the user can buy a paid version of my app. I think you right because i read about this in the "Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement" and it looks that in the market you can not collect fees for updated. Thanks Regards.